# Why does this Increment not work?

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm having some problems with this code. My problem is that with the code below, it doesn't plus the detection-ratio text with the 'incr'. It just enters the incr, but doesn't plus.

---

This is my code.

```
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    var incr=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById('detection-ratio').innerText = '0 / '+ ++incr;
         loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

---

The 'detection-ratio' text looks like this as default:

```
0 / 0
```

Then, lets say 'incr' generates the number '3', then it should increase the last 0 with 3, so it would look like this:

```
0 / 3
```

Then, lets say it's going to generate a new 'incr', lets say '5'. Then it would look like this:

```
0 / 8
```

---> But right now, it doesn't do that. It just writes the 'incr' into the 'detection-ratio' without increasing it.

Comment: `rand` and `incr` are reset in each iteration.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's so it increases with random numbers. The important part is the 'document.getElementById' part. But thanks for the fast reply though!

Comment: Can't get your problem still, please can you brief your question, could your possible add the output that you are getting along with the question.

Comment: @N20084753 - I have text with 0 / X, the X is 0 as default. Every time 'incr' generates new number it should plus it with the X value, until it reaches > 26, and then stop.

Comment: @Anders :Then, var incr += Math.floor(Math.random()*6); is the way that you can add newly generated incr to X. since Math.floor(Math.random()*6) always provides values between 0 - 6.

Comment: @N20084753 - Yes, but that's also what I need. I need it to increase the X value with a number between 0-6. Try to read my comment to the answer below.

Comment: @Anders - can you provide some sample output if possible? so that i can get it clearly.

Comment: @N20084753 - I edited the thread, I hope it's enough.

Comment: @Anders - So for instance new incr is 4 then the next output should be

A) 0 / 12 0r B) 0 / 9

Comment: @N20084753 - It should be A) 0 / 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code would help you to get the expected output, let me know if something breaks. Also stop iteration once it reaches > 26

```
var incr = 0;   
    (function loop() {
            var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
            incr +=  Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
            setTimeout(function() {
                 console.log('0 / '+ incr);
                 loop();  
            }, rand);
    }());
```

Thanks for the explanation and patience.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I will try to make it stop once it reach > 26. And thanks for helping me once again!

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to make it stop at > 26, it's a paragraph, and I tried to do this but doesn't work.
--
if (document.getElementById('detection-ratio').length > 26){
  // Stop.
} --> Nevermind, I think i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to append text to detection-ratio
if so you need to

```
document.getElementById('detection-ratio').innerText += '0 / '+ incr;
```

++ before a variable is a pre-increment operator, since you are generating random numbers i am assuming that is not actually what you want.

Comment: I am trying to increase the text aswell. The first '+' I used so it writes "0 / ", what it should write after that would be the incr. So for example, this is the default: 0 / 0, then incr generates the number '3', then it will say "0 / 3". Then next incr is gonna generate '5' and it will say "0 / 8".

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the loop recursively anyway, you may want to consider a more functional approach:

```
(function loop(startctr) {
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
        nextctr = startctr + Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        setTimeout(function() {
             console.log('0 / '+ nextctr);
             loop(nextctr);  
        }, rand);
}(0));
```